# PHP Namespaces - more efficient core functions?

Tags: php, namespaces

I've finished reading about namespaces, and one of the most practical usages comes to mind.

If namespaces can be used to avoid collision with PHP's core functions, I imagine that someone at some point has created a library that has faster core functions?

So for example, let's say strtotime() is really slow in PHP. Someone says, "Oh, this is why it's slow, it has all this functionality not everyone would need!" and releases a more efficient version of strtotime, which has no collision because of namespaces.

Does something like this exist? Have I completely missed the point of namespaces?

**Edit:** Thanks, folks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point of namespaces isn't to avoid collisions with the PHP functions names, but with other PHP code. For example, if you're using somebody else's templating library that has a class named Template, then you can't also create one yourself, even if that's the best name for the class you're building. With namespaces, all your class names exist in their own bubble. So, you can have \MyLibrary\Template and \OtherLibrary\Template.

Answer (score 3):

Why would a native method like `strtotime` be slower than a built-in-PHP version of it unless it were grossly inefficient (in which case, the native method would probably be updated)?

Quit worrying about every last microsecond of performance until you are in a position such that throwing money at the problem doesn't make it go away.

http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/12/hardware-is-cheap-programmers-are-expensive.html

Answer (score 2):

That would be a valid use for namespaces, but I'm not aware of any large-scale effort to rewrite the core library in this way.

The [SPL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.spl.php) provides improved libraries, but uses classes for organization.

If you ask me, the core PHP library's main problem isn't performance anyway - most functions are just interfaces to their C or operating system counterparts anyway. What's much more pressing is naming conventions and parameter order (problems which *could* be however also be solved using a namespace approach)